# Find Max of a Group, and Return Another Column's Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My goal is to group the `df` by the 'Grouping' column, and then find the max sales and the corresponding SKU. There a lot of sources that explain how to do the `groupby` and find max sales, but adding this additional SKU column is where I am unable to find any sources that explain what I am doing wrong.

As you can see below, I am successfully grouping by the 'Grouping' column, and displaying the max Sales per group, but the SKU is incorrect. The SKU with the highest sales for group 1 is 'E2-MKEP', and my result is 'V4-DE5U'.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [
    ['1', 'V4-DE5U', 956.64],
    ['1', 'DH-Q9OY', 642.43],
    ['1', 'E2-MKEP', 1071.6],
    ['2', 'WL-NOLZ', 389.06],
    ['2', 'JF-4E3C', 162.69],
    ['3', 'N9-DABP', 618.96],
    ['3', 'OO-JBHE', 1451.19],
]

cols = ['Grouping', 'SKU', 'Sales']

df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns = cols)

df1 = df.groupby(['Grouping']).agg(max)[['Sales', 'SKU']]

print(df1)
```

result:

```
            Sales      SKU
Grouping
1         1071.60  V4-DE5U
2          389.06  WL-NOLZ
3         1451.19  OO-JBHE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transform `max` and create a boolean mask and filter `df`:

```
msk = df.groupby(['Grouping'])['Sales'].transform('max') == df['Sales']
out = df.loc[msk, ['Sales', 'SKU']]
```

Output:

```
     Sales      SKU
2  1071.60  E2-MKEP
3   389.06  WL-NOLZ
6  1451.19  OO-JBHE
```

If you want the "Grouping" column as well, you could use `msk` on `df` without selecting columns:

```
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
  Grouping      SKU    Sales
2        1  E2-MKEP  1071.60
3        2  WL-NOLZ   389.06
6        3  OO-JBHE  1451.19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the *"Sales"* values and then drop the *"Grouping"* duplicates

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('Sales', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Grouping']).sort_values('Grouping')

df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

>>> df1
    Grouping      SKU    Sales
0        1  E2-MKEP  1071.60
1        2  WL-NOLZ   389.06
2        3  OO-JBHE  1451.19
```